# How do I pass a list of IPs by IP-API?

Tags: python

How do I pass a list of IPs by IP-API? I have a list of IP addresses that is more than 1k/2k. How can I run it using the following endpoint?

```
response = requests.post("http://ip-api.com/batch", json=[
     
     {'query': '2402:9d80:330:671e:0:0:2652:63c1'},
     {'query': '2605:6440:3008:8000:0:0:0:9060'},
     {'query': None}
      ]).json()   
response = pd.DataFrame(response) 
response
```

I want to replace the IP part with a list of IP addresses.

I have tried while i use direct IP in the Post end points it's works but from a query/list it's not working .

If I pass like this it's works :

`df = [{'query': '36.69.174.27'},] response = requests.post("ip-api.com/batch", json=df ).json() response response = pd.DataFrame(response)`

But while I use from a query/list it's not :

`df = [df] response = requests.post("ip-api.com/batch", json=df ).json() response response = pd.DataFrame(response)`

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried following the [docs](https://ip-api.com/docs/api:batch)? They seem pretty simple

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs you just need to pass the list itself:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

ips = ["2402:9d80:330:671e:0:0:2652:63c1", "2605:6440:3008:8000:0:0:0:9060", "208.80.152.201"]
response = requests.post("http://ip-api.com/batch", json=ips).json()   
response = pd.DataFrame(response) 
response
```

[image]

Comment: Hi  @Icaro Bombonato Yes I know if i put manually one by one it's work but my list coming from a data base so while I am using it it's not working.